# How to run a task in a sub-package in npm?

Tags: npm

I'm using NPM Tasks to run tasks for my app. I happen to have a sub-folder with another package.json file and want to run one of it's tasks from my package.json tasks. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It's possible. As an example, let's say we have following folder structure.

```
/src
  - package.json
  - index.js
  /api
    - package.json
    - index.js
```

Now if you want to run task of `src/api/package.json` from `src/package.json`, add something like follows to your `src/package.json`.

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "cd api && npm start",
}
```

Comment: What if I want to keep the directory same and don't want to change the directory?